# Forms are "unavailable" on mobile device

Tags: commcare

We had an issue report where a user said they were having issues submitting forms from their device and that the forms were marked "unavailable".

1. What would cause that to happen to a form?
2. How can we get these forms to submit from the device, assuming the connection is not the issue?

[edit] The forms were reported to be in the "Completed Forms" section of "Saved Forms", and the "Unavailable" is appearing beneath the name of the form in the form list.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late to answering this, but I found this post on CommCare users:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/commcare-users/7I4GCSv9vPY/ByKeOiJsAAAJ

It states "'[Unavailable]' should generally be ignored, it means CommCare had trouble loading some details about the form in question."

I would try to confirm the forms were received by the server on CommCareHQ, as this could potentially be an issue with viewing the forms on a mobile device and not with actually getting the data onto HQ. Apologies if you have already done so, in which case I am not sure why this occurred and would recommend reporting an issue with the support team.